# Getting DataStore Problem with Geotools

Tags: java, geotools

I recently found an issue with Geotools and getting the datastore for a shapefile.

If I try:

```
FileDataStore dataStore = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(file);
```

-or-

```
Map connect = new HashMap();
connect.put("url", file.toURL());

DataStore dataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(connect);
```

getDataStore() always returns null. But using:

```
ShapefileDataStore dataStore = new ShapefileDataStore(file.toURI().toURL());
```

then the dataStore is set to the shapefile. Anyone have any ideas why this is? Is this a bug with Geootools 8.2? I'm running Geotools on Tomcat 7, perhaps there is some issue with Tomcat and the DataStore and FileDataStore classes?

Thanks!

Comment: can you add what file actually contains? I suspect either it doesn't end .shp or it contains spaces and is not being encoded correctly

Answer (score 2):

Check your class path, it might miss the jars that are able to read the shape file:

Check the availabel DataStores:

```
Iterator availableStores =  DataStoreFinder.getAvailableDataStores();
LOGGER.info("List available Stores: {");
            while (availableStores.hasNext()) {
                LOGGER.info(availableStores.next().toString());
            }
LOGGER.info("}");
```

if the List is empty, then the necessary jar is missing in the classpath.

In my case, using an old version of geotools, I had to add the 
`gt2-shapefile-2.3.2` to the classpath